# Messed rounded corners

Tags: android, android-layout

I want to create custom button with rounded ***bottom right*** and ***top right*** corners.

However, I get ***bottom left*** and ***top right*** rounded instead, although my implementation seems to be ok.

*What am I doing wrong?*

I use following shape definition stored in drawable folder:

**button_shape.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:shape="rectangle">

  <solid android:color="#F66622"/>
  <padding 
    android:left="5dip"
    android:top="5dip"
    android:right="5dip"
    android:bottom="5dip"
  />
  <corners
    android:radius="20dip"
    android:bottomLeftRadius="0dip"
    android:topLeftRadius="0dip"
  />
</shape>
```

and the layout file is this:

**main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/bg"
    >
    <Button 
        android:id="@+id/btnFoo"
        android:text="@string/btn_foo_title"
        android:background="@drawable/button_shape"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="5dip"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:textSize="26sp"
    />
</RelativeLayout>
```

This is the result:

[image: messed corners]

I also tried to define each corner radius separately in the button_shape file

```
...
<corners
    android:bottomLeftRadius="0dip"
    android:topLeftRadius="0dip"
    android:bottomRightRadius="20dip"
    android:topRightRadius="20dip"
/>
...
```

... with the same result.

Is it possible that this functionality is somehow messed up in Android SDK?

Comment: I doubt it that the functionality is messed up! Do Project -> Clean, and see if it resolves the problem.

Comment: I tried that, didn't help at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Silly question, but did you try rounding bottomLeft and see if it rounds the bottom-right corner?  I know it's not a true solution, but work-arounds are nice too.  If it looks the way you want, it doesn't matter how you achieve it.

Comment: When I change it to <corners android:radius="20dip" **android:bottomRightRadius="0dip"** android:topLeftRadius="0dip"/>, the result is what I expect. However, this workaround isn't somehow satisfying for me :-)

Comment: If you're coding for self satisfaction, then I'm not sure what to tell you.  Chances are this is a bug nobody found yet cuz nobody rounded fewer than 4 corners before or nobody cared about the bug enough to submit it.  If you're coding to make a functioning app, however, work-arounds are imperfect but a working app is satisfaction enough in itself.  At least, if that's your reason for not using it, my answer deserves a rating :D